# Refresh spinner data

Tags: android

I have an application with a Spinner whos data is populated by a cursor from the database.  Works great if there is something in the database table on startup.  However, if I add something to the database after the app is running my spinner always shows that it has zero choices, even if one was there to begin with.

My code is as follows.  The adapter.getCursor().requery(); did no good.  I would like the Spinner to update its choices when the user clicks on it and I found a couple posts on StackOverflow that say you have to use the TextView behind the Spinner for the OnClickListener.  However, for me that did nothing.  Mostly likely because I'm missing one minor

```
    c1 = myDbHelper.readCars();
    startManagingCursor(c1);

    // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
    String[] from = new String[]{"nickname"};
    // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c1, from, to); 
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinVehicle.setAdapter(adapter);

    txtVehiclePrompt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            adapter.getCursor().requery();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked that your cursor returns any values?

Comment: Yes, it returns values fine on a fresh start of the program, just not once its running.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I got it figured out.  I needed to close the adapter, stop managing the cursor, close the cursor & close the db helper in the `onSuspend()` method then set everything back up in the onResume method since I was using a seperate activity to add records to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the underlying data and call notifyDataSetChanged()

```
 list.clear();
 //list modify
  list.add("A");
  list.add("B");
 dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```