# Android - Get single String value using HashMap

Tags: android, hashmap

In my application, I've preloaded Spinner with `ArrayList`.The ArrayList contains multiple `Text String`. These text Strings will serve as message `template` user can select from spinner. Also I want these String keyword might be replaced with variable when message is being sent. Like "Text" will be replaced with EditText content, "Phone No " replaced with Sender's no, "Date" replaced with Message Date

I have tried to search on HashMap in Android, but getting problem:

```
HashMap<String, String> template=new HashMap<String, String>();
 template.put("Text", editText.getText().toString());
 template.put("Phone No",senderPhone);
 template.put("Date",receivedDate);
```

now I want to display it as Single string like Text, Phone No, Date. can this String be editable.

Comment: string x=(String)template.get("Text"); is the way to get the value of a HashMap.. kindly explain well what you want to ask..

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from Hashmap, use:

```
String Text   = (String)template.get("Text");
String phoneNo= (String)template.get("PhoneNo");
String date   = (String)template.get("Date");
```

You can combine all the above 3 and display it where ever you want to
For Example,

```
String displayString = Text + "-" + phoneNo + " -" + date
editText.setText(displayString);
```

This edit text by default would be editable until and unless you make it non editable.!

**EDIT:** (Refer comments for purpose of Edit)

(1) Set the edit text value as the value selected by user from spinner.

```
editText.setText(displayString);
```

(2) After user selects and modifies the edittext, let the user click a confirm button.

(3) In confirm button code, add the value to your local storage (**IF REQUIRED!**).

(4) Refresh the spinner to include this modified value

To refresh, if you want to modify the existing list in spinner then refer [Refresh spinner data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999896/refresh-spinner-data)

To refresh, if you want to keep the existing spinner list as such, and add the new value, then refer [dynamic add data to spinner but not update the data on the spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828675/dynamic-add-data-to-spinner-but-not-update-the-data-on-the-spinner)

Comment: this code i need to write after my hash map code and also my displayString need to be editable

Comment: The displayString will be set to an EditText box. The EditText would be editable by default. User can edit the value in the textbox anytime.

Comment: can displayString be modify by user like: `PhoneNo` modified to occur before `Text`and also the modified displayString be updated in Spinner, same like we edit/modify String in database

Comment: Yes sure, change displayString =  phoneNo + "-" + Text +  " -" + date;

Comment: Once user updates value, set the value to the template as template.put("Text", editText.getText().toString());  I assume, you would only be fetching this value and showing it in spinner.

Comment: what I want is: suppose a spinner contain multiple text String like : How are you?, Will be leaving late, can we meet. Is it possible for user to select any of the template, edit it, update the edited template in spinner.

Comment: Yes, You can do it. (1) Set the edit text value as the value selected by user from spinner. (2)  After user selects and modifies the edittext, let the user click a confirm button. (3) In confirm button code, add the value to your local storage. (4) Refresh the spinner to include this modified value.

Comment: will check and upvote. can you also tell how to refresh spinner to add modified values, if any error will get back to you. and Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (String name : template.values())
{
    builder.append(name + " ");
}

String templateString = builder.toString();
```

This will get all the values from the `HashMap` using the `values()` and concat it into a `String`